# C to WebAssembly fails when indexing pointer

Tags: c, webassembly

I'm experimenting with C to WebAssembly. But I fail to understand the following:

```c
int atAddressN(unsigned int idx) {
  unsigned int* intptr = 0;
  return intptr[idx];
}

int atAddress2(unsigned int idx) {
  unsigned int* intptr = 0;
  return intptr[2];
}
```

Results in the following wasm/wat:

```
(module
 (table 0 anyfunc)
 (memory $0 1)
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (export "atAddressN" (func $atAddressN))
 (export "atAddress2" (func $atAddress2))
 (func $atAddressN (; 0 ;) (param $0 i32) (result i32)
  (unreachable)
  (unreachable)
 )
 (func $atAddress2 (; 1 ;) (param $0 i32) (result i32)
  (i32.load offset=8
   (i32.const 0)
  )
 )
)
```

So the second function is fine, but the first one just results in `(unreachable)`. Should I do something else to get it to compile ok?

Comment: Both functions leads to *undefined behavior* as you dereference null pointers.

Comment: The memory is layed out beforehand (calling from JS with Webassembly.Memory), it should be fine in principle.

Comment: I'd start experimenting with normal C to start.

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer dereference appears to be a problem indeed, changing to:

```c
int atAddressN(unsigned int* intptr, unsigned int idx) {
  return intptr[idx];
}

int atAddress2(unsigned int* intptr, unsigned int idx) {
  return intptr[2];
}
```

results in

```
(module
 (table 0 anyfunc)
 (memory $0 1)
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (export "atAddressN" (func $atAddressN))
 (export "atAddress2" (func $atAddress2))
 (func $atAddressN (; 0 ;) (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32) (result i32)
  (i32.load
   (i32.add
    (get_local $0)
    (i32.shl
     (get_local $1)
     (i32.const 2)
    )
   )
  )
 )
 (func $atAddress2 (; 1 ;) (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32) (result i32)
  (i32.load offset=8
   (get_local $0)
  )
 )
)
```

I'll just call the function with `0` as the first argument then.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test case that calls the function, compile with debug symbols, `-g` and step through it with a debugger like `gdb`. Here is a typical debug session.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x0000000000401147 in atAddressN (idx=3) at e.c:4
    4         return intptr[idx];

```
(gdb) print intptr[idx]
Cannot access memory at address 0xc
```

The gdb `print` command reveals the problem.

There isn't much special about WebAssembly when it comes to tests. These kids of tests will generally compile as an executable just as well.

```
//test.c
int main (){ printf("int 3 is %i\n", atAddressN(3)); return 0;}
```

Comment: It might depend on the WebAssembly engine, but when used from Chrome, you pre-assign a Memory to the engine, which then appears to start at 0x0. I'm not sure if this is common in all WebAssembly implementations though, although I haven't found any other mechanism to determine to which address this memory is mapped.

Comment: I haven't tried it. But if someone wanted to write self-modifying code in WebAssembly, it would be something like answer #7447013. Changing permission on the memory and modifying the resultant WebAssembly like Tigress does. Perhaps using no compiler optimizations, `-O0` so broken code does not get optimized out.

Comment: I think WebAssembly doesn't allow access to the code memory. There are also no stack pointers, it's all pretty strict/safe in that sense. AFAIK the heap starts at 0x0 (if there is no const data). Not sure what Tigress does, maybe there is some sort of embedded VM?

Comment: Yeah. Tigress is virtualizing. That's probably how they can make that claim. https://tigress.wtf/introduction.html Supposing there is no restraints on implementing ones own interpreters and VMs in WebAssembly for purposes of obfuscation. There is also the possibility of buffer overflows and other exploits, but no professional product should be relying on those...